# Find object knowing one of its values in array

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have following `companies` collection in mongoDB

```
{
    c00:
        {
            _id: c00,
            name: 'acme',
            results: [
                0: { _id: 'a10', name: 'foo', visible: true },
                1: { _id: 'a11', name: 'bar', visible: false }
            ],
        },
    c01:
        {
            _id: c01,
            name: 'apra'
            results: [
                0: { _id: 'b10', name: 'foo', visible: false },
                1: { _id: 'b11', name: 'bar', visible: true },
                2: { _id: 'b12', name: 'qux', visible: true },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to find proper 'result' having company._id and result.name, or get all results for a company, then use `find`/`filter` ?
I need to obtain `{ _id: 'b11', name: 'bar', visible: true }` having `company.id === c01` and `name === 'bar'`, where name is unique for results of some company

Answer (score 0):

You could just [query the array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/):

```
collection.find({ "results._id": "whatever", "results.name": "foo" })
```

Comment: w/o specifying company._id?